# How can I save a collection, or atleast a portion of it, in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to maintain the order of models in a collection that are in a model and be able to save it to the server. I know I can save the individual models, but when I save the "parent model" that contains the collection the attribute holding the collection is now saved.

Is there a way to do this? Below is my code. And I know it probably isn't the best, I am still learning.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var WO = Backbone.Model.extend({
                wonum: null,
                part: null,
                desc: null,
                initialize: function()
                {
                    this.url = '/rest/wo/'+this.get('wonum');
                }
            });

            var WOView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: "tr",
                className: "wo",
                initialize: function(options)
                {
                    this.render = _.bind(this.render, this);
                },
                render: function()
                {
                    $(this.el).html("<td>"+this.model.get('wonum')+"</td><td>"+this.model.get('part')+"</td><td>"+this.model.get('desc')+"</td>");
                    return this;
                }
            });


            var WOs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: WO,
                url: '/rest/section/wos/'
            });

            var Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
                defaults: {
                    name : "Section"
                },
                wos: [],
                url: '/rest/section/',
                initialize: function()
                {
                    this.wos = new WOs();
                    this.wos.url += this.id;
                    this.url += this.id;
                }
            });

            var SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: "table",
                initialize: function()
                {
                    _(this).bindAll('add','remove');
                    var that = this;
                    this._woViews = [];

                    this.model.wos.each(this.add);

                    this.model.wos.bind('add', this.add);
                },
                add: function(woObj)
                {
                    var wov = new WOView({
                        model: woObj,
                        id: woObj.get('wonum')});
                    this._woViews.push(wov);
                    if(this._rendered)
                        $(this.el).append(wov.render().el);
                    this.model.save();
                },
                render: function()
                {
                    this._rendered = true;
                    var that = this;
                    $(this.el).empty();
                    $(this.el).append("<thead><th>WO</th><th>Part</th><th>Desc</th></thead>");
                    $(this.el).append("<tbody>");
                    _(this._woViews).each(function(wov)
                    {
                        $(that.el).append(wov.render().el);
                    });
                    $(this.el).append("</tbody>");
                    return this;
                }
            });

            var sec = new Section({id: 1});
            sec.wos.add({
                wonum: 1001,
                part: 'p1001',
                desc: 'd1001'});
            sec.wos.add({
                wonum: 1002,
                part: 'p1002',
                desc: 'd1002'});
            var secv = new SectionView({model: sec, id: sec.get('id')});
            $("body").append(secv.render().el);
            $("#addwo").bind("click",function()
            {
                secv.add(new WO({
                    wonum: 1005,
                    part: 'p1005',
                    desc: 'd1005'}));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='addwo'>Add WO</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using the Collection's comparator function (which you can set) to preserve the order of the collection.  This comparator would potentially use a property of the models; so for instance, the model's name or even a position property.

Using this approach, you would just save each model independently, but have the collection potentially refresh itself (where it would use the comparator to preserve the desired order).

Comment: My problem is I don't have a property on the models that can be used. The elements will be re-arranged by the user on the page. I think I can get it to work, but I am having issues modifying the models once they are in the collection.